# Calculate distribution of function of random variable using total probability formula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, bayes-theorem

Let Y be a function of the random variable X as follows:
    $$  Y=
\left\{ 
    \begin{aligned}
         X, & \quad X\ge 0 \\ 
         X^2,& \quad X\le0
    \end{aligned}
\right.
 $$
compute $f_{Y}{(y)}$ in terms of $f_{X}{(x)}$, where $f_{X}{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

I use total probability formula to derive an equation:
$$
P(Y\le y)  =P(Y\le y | X \ge 0)P(X\ge 0) + P(Y\le y | X \le 0)P(X \le 0)
$$
Then:
$$
P(Y\le y) = P(X \le y | X \ge 0)P(X\ge 0) + P(X^2 \le y | X \le 0)P(X\le 0)
$$

Finally I derive cumulative distribution function $F_{Y}{(y)}$, and obtain $f_{Y}{(y)}$ from it.

However, my answer is not correct. I think the problem may lie in above two steps, so I was wondering if maybe anyone could point me out what is wrong with above two equitations?

Comment: Why the conditioning? To apply your approach, simply use the fact that, for every $y\geqslant0$, $$[Y\leqslant y]=[-\sqrt{y}\leqslant X\leqslant y].$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for $x\geq0$: $$[Y\le x]=[-\sqrt{x}\le X\le x]$$ Hence: $$F_Y(x)=F_X(x)-F_X(-\sqrt{x})$$
Differentiating: $$f_Y(x)=f_X(x)+\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}f_X(-\sqrt{x})$$
Now substitute.

Comment: Wow, thank you @drhab. Now many of my previous solutions can be simplified. Since you give the formal solution, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Credit goes to @did.

Answer (score 1):

What have you got for $f_Y(y)$ ? Using your method, I got $f_Y(y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{-y^2/2}+\dfrac1{2\sqrt{y}}e^{-y/2}\right)$, for $y>0$ of course. Why isn't that correct ?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. Could you elaborate on your procedures to get this answer? My answer has an additional multiplier 1/2 in 1/sqrt(2*pi)

Comment: @yusixie This might be due to a faulty application of the conditioning in your decomposition.

Comment: @Did    In my decompositions, I differentiate $P(X \le y | X \ge 0)P(X \ge 0)$ , then get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}^{-y^2/2}\frac{1}{2}$. Can you point me out what is wrong with this decomposition?

Comment: @yusixie First, you do not do that since "that" is equating a CDF of some sort with some PDF. Second, $P(X\le y\mid X\ge0)=P(0\le X\le y)/P(X\ge0)=2(\Phi(y)-\Phi(0))$, not $=\Phi(y)-\Phi(0)$. To sum up, conditioning-deconditioning was unnecessary and led you into the wall.

Comment: @Did   OMG. X is a standard normal random variable and as you said, $P(X \le y | X \ge 0)=P(0 \le X \le y)/P(X \ge 0) = 2 ( \Phi(y) -  \Phi(0)  )$. I think this is why I have an additional $1/2$. In addition, my conditioning-decomposition is really dumb. I will try your elegant solution in other problems. Thank you Did.